# Get all parents of elements without using ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<li>
    First Node
  <ul>
    <li>child</li>
    <ul>
        <li id="idTest">child of child</li>
    </ul>
    <li>child2</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want to add a style to all the `ul`'s that are parents of the `li` with the id "idTest". Notice that there are no id's to all of the `ul`'s, and that the style shouldn't be added to the `li` "child2"

I couldn't find a proper answer, please help.

Comment: Your HTML seems invalid: the only direct children that ul elements should have are li elements. (If you want a nested list the child ul should be inside an li.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your HTML is invalid, `ul` elements cannot have `ul` elements as direct children. You'd have to put your nested `ul` inside an `li` or similar.

You can get the parent element of an element from its `parentNode` property (repeatedly if necessary). So for instance:

```
var element = document.getElementById("idTest").parentNode;
while (element.tagName !== "BODY") {
    if (element.tagName === "UL") {
        // Add the style
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
}
```

Example (with corrected HTML):

```js
var element = document.getElementById("idTest").parentNode;
while (element.tagName !== "BODY") {
    if (element.tagName === "UL") {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
}
```

```css
/* The default display for UL is block, so I assume you're hiding them or similar */
ul {
  display: hide;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      First Node
    <ul>
      <li>child</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="idTest">child of child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Notice that...and that the style shouldn't be added to the li "child2"

If you add the style to the `ul` that is the grandparent of `#idTest`, depending on what style it is, it may be inherited. If so, you may need to override that style on descendant `ul`s or `li`s.

You've said in a comment you'll be adding `display: block`, so that's not a problem; `display` isn't inherited.

Comment: I want to add the style "display: block;"
can it be inhertied?

also - what do you suggest doing istead of `ul` inside `ul`? 
Thanks

Comment: @D.Griff: The `display` property isn't inherited, so that's fine. Re `ul` in `ul`: Put it in an `li`. :-) It's perfectly normal to have `ul > li > ul > li`, but you can't have `ul > ul`.

Comment: i tried your func and received the error " Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined" any idea why?

Comment: @D.Griff: My code above will not trigger that error, you must have miscopied it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with jQuery instead of pure javascript you can try [`.parentsUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

**example**

```js
$('.activatoror').click(function() {
 $('#idTest').parentsUntil($('.ul-1'), 'ul').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul, li {
  color: black;
}
.activatoror {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-1">
  <li>1st li of first ul</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="ul-2">
      <li>1st li of 2nd ul</li>
      <li>
        <ul class="ul-3">
          <li id="idTest">1st li of 3rd ul (#idTest)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>3rd li of 2nd ul</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="activatoror">click me</div>

</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/e5vsLwsu/